# Bug in my Floyd-Warshall C++ implementation

Tags: c++, graph, floyd-warshall

I've got a assignment for my college, already implemented Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford successfully, but I'm in trouble on this one. Everything looks fine, but it's not giving me the correct answer.

Here's the code:

```
void FloydWarshall()
{
    //Also assume that n is the number of vertices and edgeCost(i,i) = 0

    int path[500][500];

    /* A 2-dimensional matrix. At each step in the algorithm, path[i][j] is the shortest path
       from i to j using intermediate vertices (1..k−1).  Each path[i][j] is initialized to
       edgeCost(i,j) or infinity if there is no edge between i and j.
    */

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= nvertices ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j <= nvertices ; j++)
            path[i][j] = INFINITY;

    for(int j = 0 ; j < narestas ; j++) //narestas = number of edges
    {
        path[arestas[j]->v1][arestas[j]->v2] = arestas[j]->peso; //peso = weight of the edge (aresta = edge)
        path[arestas[j]->v2][arestas[j]->v1] = arestas[j]->peso;
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= nvertices ; i++) //path(i, i) = 0
        path[i][i] = 0;

    //test print, it's working fine
    //printf("\n\n\nResultado FloydWarshall:\n");
    //for(int i = 1 ; i <= nvertices ; i++)
    //    printf("distancia ao vertice %d:  %d\n", i, path[1][i]);


    // Here's the problem, it messes up, and even a edge who costs 4, and the minimum is 4, it prints 2.

    //for k = 1 to n
    for(int k = 1 ; k <= nvertices ; k++)
       //for i = 1 to n
       for(int i = 1 ; i <= nvertices ; i++)
           //for j := 1 to n
           for(int j = 1 ; j <= nvertices ; j++)
               if(path[i][j] > path[i][k] + path[k][j])
                   path[i][j] = path[i][k] + path[k][j];


    printf("\n\n\nResultado FloydWarshall:\n");
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= nvertices ; i++)
        printf("distancia ao vertice %d:  %d\n", i, path[1][i]);
}
```

I'm using this graph example I made:

```
6 7

1 2 4
1 5 1
2 3 1
2 5 2
5 6 3
6 4 6
3 4 2
```

means we have 6 vertices (1 to 6), and 7 edges (1,2) with weight 4... etc..

If anyone need more info, i'm up to giving it, just tired of looking at this code and not finding an error.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, i took a break to eat something and found out the error.

Infinity is defined as INT_MAX, so as soon as you add something to it, it turns negative.

I only defined to something big (to my problem, like over9000, no graph path will take more than that), and it's working fine.

But may i know why you suggested that Yin? i didn't get that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(path[i][j] > path[i][k] + path[k][j])
  path[i][j] = path[i][k] + path[k][j];
```

make some check here. e.g. if path[i][k] and path[k][j] are non-infinite, and i!=j i!=k and k!=j.

Answer (score 0):

Also, aren't the starts and ends of your iteration over path off by one in several places? You probably want them running from 0 to `nvertices-1`; i.e. `for (int i = 0; i < nvertices; i++)`.